# horizontal navigation with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have have an app that has a two levels of navigation, the main level [1] has the main menu, settings and other things like that. in the menu i have a list of customers and when i click on a customer I load my customer fragment which is part of a second level of navigation [2]. The customer has 4 different pages, or fragments, associated with it. I am using the fragment transaction to keep the menu in the stack via `transaction.addToBackStack("toCustomer')` whenever the user navigates to a customer. Now when i hit back from a customer it takes me back to the main menu as expected.

The problem I am having is when I switch to the other customer fragments (using a `transaction.replace()` call without `addToBackStack()`, hitting the back button does nothing the first time, and then closes out of the app the second. I would like the user to go back to the main menu from any of the 4 customer fragments, but i cannot figure out how to do this.

Here is what I have for when the user clicks on a customer from the main menu:

```
 FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
 Fragment fragment = new Cust_1();
 transaction.hide(MainMenu.this);
 transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
 transaction.addToBackStack("toCustomer");
 transaction.commit();
```

And here is what I use for when a user clicks on one of the other customer page buttons:

```
Fragment fragment = customerFragments[clickedButton];
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
   .commit();
```

where customerFragments is just an array of fragments to use based on what button was clicked. The buttons all work fine, just the back button functionality is messed up.